# How to fix show method while using MetroMessageBox

Tags: c#

Right now I am exploring the modern metroframework in c# but right now I got stuck with this one thing.

If I make a MetroMessageBox by doing the following:

```
MetroMessageBox.Show("", "", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
```

I get a red line under my 'show' . The error in the errorlist tells me the following: No overload for method 'Show' takes 4 arguments.

I already thank you all for the help

Comment: `MetroMessageBox.Show` methood dont need 4 parameters. what you looking for?

Comment: Well what do you think the error means?  It's pretty obvious.

Comment: http://denricdenise.info/2015/09/how-to-use-metromessagebox/

Comment: thanks for the link to the video but it didn't solve it. Here is a the problem there is right now.Check the link for the screenshot https://snag.gy/Rahn8Y.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`MetroMessageBox.Show()` has other parameters than a Windows Forms MessageBox.

```
MetroMessageBox.Show(this, "MessageText", "TitleText")
```

Comment: Well I tried your awnser but without succes. Right now it underlines the MetroMessageBox title and this. About the title it says it cannot convert a string to a int and the 'this' says cannot convert from current class to System.Windows.Forms.IWin32Window

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
   MetroFramework.MetroMessageBox.Show(this, "Your message here.","Title Here",
                        MessageBoxButtons.OK,MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
```

Comment: thank you but this didn't solve it. In the reaction beneath my main post I posted a reaction with a image of the current problem

Comment: I think this problem in package this version

Comment: asdnafn can you be more specific?

Comment: you can check `MessageBoxIcon.Warning` instead `MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation` ?

Comment: doesn't matter gives the same problem

Comment: I think you use MetroFramework package .There are something problem this package. You can use [MetroModernUI](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MetroModernUI/) instead MetroFramework